# Cannot build a platform-specific XAML Browser Application in visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, 64-bit, xbap

I am trying build XBAP by setting platform target to x86, and I got the following error.

> Cannot build a platform-specific XAML
>   Browser Application. If HostInBrowser
>   property is set to 'True', either do
>   not set the PlatformTarget property or
>   set it to 'AnyCpu'

Is there any reason why this is disabled?

Comment: I don't know why, but can share what problem you're trying to work around?

Comment: Actually I am not able to open the XBAP Application in windows 7 X64 computers.

Comment: Can you share details on the error that you get? Also, are you running the 64bit version of the web browser, or the 32bit version. I assume you're running IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's disabled because you can't control your user(s) browser. XAML Browser Application are browser independent.

You can avoid this error by targeting Any CPU on configuration manager.